# Using Exit inside IF:ENDIF control structure

Tags: php, wordpress

It's a fictitious example. And I want to understand "What really happens when using EXIT in this code":

```
function my_template_redirect() {
    $page = get_query_var('pagename'); //get some value
    if ( $page == 'products' ): //compare with something
        //show products
        EXIT;
    elseif ( $page == 'product' ): //compare "else"
        //show product
        EXIT;
    endif;
}
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect' );
```

Ok. Step by step execute (my own logical version)

```
|-code executing
|-filter callback my_template_redirect()
|-if start (or else)
   |-exit
   |-start execute new template
```

What happen after EXIT call? Control structure IF:ENDIF automatically closes? Or still opened in new code? Is this bad way to organize code?

Thanks in advance!

PS I'm using WP example for better understanding my bad English :)

Comment: `exit` terminates the script. Nothing can happen "after" calling `exit` because the script is dead. e.g. RTFM: http://php.net/exit

Comment: You'd probably be better off using `return` in these instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [PHP docs on exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php), you'll find that `exit` completely terminates the current script.

However:

> Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit is called.

Comment: I know this. What about IF:ENDIF?

Comment: As I mentioned, using `exit` in your example above, will completely terminate the script. It doesn't matter whether it's in `if` or `endif`. The function just stops running.

Comment: Still opened or will close? It possible leak memory?

Comment: No, it's not still open. The script terminates. Terminates. At the end of any PHP process, the process ends just like any other program. Terminates. No memory is left over. Terminates. No memory leak. Terminates. ;-)

Comment: :) Thanks! +1! But I'm waiting one day (maybe anyone has another opinion). I like your answer :)